# How to close a primefaces push socket connection

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I have a problem with primefaces push. I use jsf2.2, jetty9.1 with cdi1.2 and primefaces5.0.

In my view i connect to a socket via

```
<p:socket id="chat-socket" onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/#{chatPresenter.activeChatChannel}" />
```

which works just fine. the handleMessage function is called on every push event. But i need to be able to disconnect from that socket with an ajax button.

```
<p:commandButton value="Ajax Discconect" onclick="disconnectFromSocket()" />
```

I could not find a built in method in the primefaces socket doc to close the connection.
My idea is to call a javascript function if the commandButton is clicked, that closes the socket connection.

Unfortunately i have no idea how to get the open primefaces socket connections in javascript and if its possible to close them this way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give PF('chat-socket').disconnect(); a try ?

Comment: This is soooo simple! Thank you. Just a small addition: the p:socket tag needs to have the attribute widgetVar=COSTUM-NAME and the javascript method looks as follows: PF('CUSTOM-NAME'). Works like a charm.